# The simple present tense has been used with "since"

Tags: present-tense, time

> I love you since forever.

In the sentence, the simple present tense has been used with "since". I'd 
like to know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: ***Please do not use the Grammar tag.*** It is vague, and people seriously want to deprecate it.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it is not grammatical.  This is because the present tense ("I love you") refers to things that are happening now, like reporting a current event or state ("I love this restaurant") or happen in general ("I eat here every week").

**But phrases with *since* usually require the *[present perfect](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-use.html)***, because *since* means "[from a past time to now](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/since)".  For example, "This restaurant has been open since last May."

**So the grammatical way to phrase it is "I have loved you since forever."**

But we're not quite done!  ["Since forever" is a very informal phrasing.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=since%20forever)  You can use it and people will generally understand it to mean "for a very long time", but the more common phrasing would be **"I have loved you forever."**

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct to use since forever in the present simple, though it's understandable. Grammatically, you should say:

I have loved you forever.